# httpContextAccessor null when called by service to applyBaseActions

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, httpcontext

I have a baseDbContext like this:

```
public abstract class BaseDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

        private Guid tenantId => this.GetTenantId();
        private Guid tenantCountryId => this.GetTenantCountryId();
        private static MethodInfo ConfigureEntityDefaultsMethodInfo = typeof(BaseDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(ConfigureEntityDefaults), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        public BaseDbContext() { }
        public BaseDbContext(DbContextOptions<BaseDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : base(options)
        {
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }
        public BaseDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : base(options)
        {
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }
        public BaseDbContext(DbContextOptions<HostDataContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : base(options)
        {
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }
```

Basically my service is calling the saveChangesAsync() method in this class :

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            ApplyBaseEntityActions();
            return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        protected virtual void ApplyBaseEntityActions()
        {
            var userId = GetCurrentProfileId();

            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList())
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        ApplyBaseEntityAddedActions(entry, userId);
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        ApplyBaseEntityUpdatedActions(entry, userId);
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        ApplyBaseEntityDeletedActions(entry, userId);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

protected virtual Guid GetCurrentProfileId()
        {
            Guid result = Guid.Empty;
            if (_contextAccessor != null && _contextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
            {
                result = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.GetProfileId();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

But when it reaches GetCurrentProfileID the _contextAccessor is null and so I am getting empty Guid Value.

Edit :
This is how I am injecting the httpcontetAccessor to my class which is calling dbContext :

```
public SellRateService(

            EzyDataContext dbContext,
            IConfiguration config,
            IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,            ILogger<SellRateService> logger,
            IEmailHelper emailHelper )
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _config = config;
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailHelper = emailHelper;

        }
```

and this in services :
`services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`
Can anyone please help on why the contextAccessor is null and and how should I remedy it.
Thanks.

Comment: There's some debugging information missing from this question, because it's unclear which constructor of `BaseDbContext` is called, which derivative is calling that constructor, whether they supply `null` to that constructor, or whether some (not posted) code clears `_contextAccessor`. You might want to set some breakpoints and step through the application to find this out. Also, you might want to add some protections such as Guard Clauses and use the `readonly` keyword on `_contextAccessor` to ensure `null` is never provided.